# React js automatically changed "jsx": "react-jsx" to "jsx": "preserve"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I try to run the react project the `tsconfig` file has been automatically changed `"jsx": "react-jsx"` to `"jsx": "preserve"` after that i'm getting this kind of errors

```
×
←→1 of 3 errors on the page
ReferenceError: React is not defined
App
C:/Users/AntonyPraveenkumarMo/01_antony/Personalspace/fullstack/React MUI/react-mui-demo/src/App.tsx:6
  3 | import CustomRoutes from './components/Routes';
  4 | 
  5 | function App() {
> 6 |   return (
  7 |     <div className="App">
  8 |         {/* <MuiTypography /> */}
  9 |       <CustomRoutes />
View compiled
renderWithHooks
C:/Users/AntonyPraveenkumarMo/01_antony/Personalspace/fullstack/React MUI/react-mui-demo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14141
  14138 |     ReactCurrentDispatcher$1.current = HooksDispatcherOnMountInDEV;
  14139 |   }
  14140 | }
> 14141 | var children = Component(props, secondArg); // Check if there was a render phase update
        | ^  14142 | 
  14143 | if (didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass) {
  14144 |   // Keep rendering in a loop for as long as render phase updates continue to
View compiled
mountIndeterminateComponent
C:/Users/AntonyPraveenkumarMo/01_antony/Personalspace/fullstack/React MUI/react-mui-demo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17432
  17429 |   }
  17430 |   setIsRendering(true);
  17431 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
> 17432 |   value = renderWithHooks(null, workInProgress, Component, props, context, renderLanes);
        | ^  17433 |   hasId = checkDidRenderIdHook();
  17434 |   setIsRendering(false);
  17435 | }
View compiled
beginWork
C:/Users/AntonyPraveenkumarMo/01_antony/Personalspace/fullstack/React MUI/react-mui-demo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18728
  18725 | switch (workInProgress.tag) {
  18726 |   case IndeterminateComponent:
  18727 |     {
> 18728 |       return mountIndeterminateComponent(current, workInProgress, workInProgress.type, renderLanes);
        | ^  18729 |     }
  18730 |   case LazyComponent:
  18731 |     {
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/Users/AntonyPraveenkumarMo/01_antony/Personalspace/fullstack/React MUI/react-mui-demo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3733
  3730 | function callCallback() {
  3731 |   didCall = true;
  3732 |   restoreAfterDispatch();
> 3733 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
       | ^  3734 |   didError = false;
  3735 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  3736 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/Users/AntonyPraveenkumarMo/01_antony/Personalspace/fullstack/React MUI/react-mui-demo/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3777
  3774 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  3775 | 
  3776 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 3777 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
       | ^  3778 | if (windowEventDescriptor) {
  3779 |   Object.defineProperty(window, 'event', windowEventDescriptor);
  3780 | }
```

These errors only happen when I try to install the package `npm i @mui/styles`.

My project is typescript project please help me to solve this. and one more request please explain about the `tsconfig` and it's use

Comment: Possible reasons are 1. you didn't load React.JS into your page, 2. you loaded it after the above script into your page. Solution is load the JS file before the above shown script.

P.S

Possible solutions.

If you mention react in externals section inside webpack configuration, then you must load react js files directly into your html before bundle.js
Make sure you have the line import React from 'react';

Comment: React is a frontend library, it doesn't go about changing your config files. For details about `tsconfig`, you should [read the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig)